# Ant design: get Id from datepicker in onChange

Tags: reactjs, redux, datepicker, antd

I've a form with multiple Datepickers in a React-Redux app and I need to know the id of the Datepicker that has been used.

When the datepickers are created I can assign a function to the `onChange` method (this method has two params (dates) to use).

```
<DatePicker
   title={field.title}
   placeholder={field.title}    
   format={"YYYY/MM/DD"}
   size={params.fieldsize}
   onChange={this.handleDatePickerChange}
/>
```

I need to retrieve the id of the Datepicker inside the `handleDatePickerChange` function:

```
handleDatePickerChange = (date, dateString) => {
   // get the id
   ...
}
```

The (date, dateString) are the params of the returned callback function. See method onChange in  https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#DatePicker

> A callback function, can be executed when the selected time is changing.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can send an extra variable in `onChange` function as below:

```
onChange={(date, dateString) => this.handleDatePickerChange(date, dateString, 1)}
```

And then in `handleDatePickerChange` method you can get it as given below:

```
handleDatePickerChange = (date, dateString, id) => {
   console.log(id);
   ...
}
```

I have created a demo on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/4rrj8nypz0).

Comment: I would preferred that the onChange method trigger an event that pass an Event object.